# Find all the values of the paramater 'a', for which the domain of the function contains only one integer.

Tags: analysis, integers

Recently I have been studying high school mathematics in Russia. Here they have classification tests that allow you to get into the top universities. In these tests, there are some interesting problems, and it is not hard to find russian websites dedicated to explaining how such problems may be solved. I have been looking for sites in English with similar problems that may explain them, but I have not been lucky.

The following is a problem involving a parameter value 'a' and you have to find the values of 'a' that make the domain of a function fulfill certain criteria.

**For the following function, find all the values of the parameter 'a', for which the domain of the function contains only one integer. y, x and a, may only be real numbers.**

### $y = \sqrt{a^{x+0.5}+a^{4}\sqrt{x}-x^{0.5+x\log_x a}-a^{4.5}}$

I am mostly interested in finding english sources where I may find more problems like this and maybe even their discussion. If you fancy a solution to the above problem, please let me know the sources that you feel helped you better understand the problem.

---

I found the problem in this file: (all in Russian)
http://gimnazia5bryansk.narod.ru/romashko/z2.doc

You can find other problems like this in these sites: (also in Russian)
http://postupivuz.ru/vopros/8521.htm

http://xn--i1abbnckbmcl9fb.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8/410368/

NOTE: There are some similar problems in the exchange, but they usually involve making the roots into something specific. I believe this problem is different enough to merit at least a small discussion.

Comment: Maybe I'm just overlooking something but ... man this feels a lot like one of those so-called "coffin problems." I can't read Russian so I can't even begin to attempt to read the other problems, but this just seems ridiculously difficult. Then again maybe I just wouldn't survive doing math in Russia. >.>

Comment: What happens if you set $a=1$? Just to try ...

Comment: It is not very difficult. Just find the region where for all x and a, the square root is not defined. Inside that region anything that makes the root cero will be the domain of the function.

Comment: I was a high school pupil at the last years of Soviet Union. I was a regular top math competition winner in my country and I didn’t respest parameter related problems (and top universities :-) ) because of their artificiality, so they usually should be solved by a boring routine simplification. By once my teacher proposed to me a parameter related problem whose solution turned out to be not so straightforward. I was so surprised that I even bought a book containing this problem. I guess it can be a good sourse which your are looking for. Unofrtunately, it is also in Russian.

Comment: The book is “Задачи с параметрами” by П. И. Горнштейн, В.Б. Полонский, and  М.С. Якир. In its annotation is written that “The book contains more than 700 problems with parameters, most of which were proposed at entrance exams in leading universities. The book material is partitioned not only into chapters and sections, but also into subsections devoted to special types of problems or methods of their solutions. Answers are provided for all exersises”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we just want the thing under the sqrt to be non-negative.

$$y = \sqrt{a^{x+0.5}+a^{4}\sqrt{x}-x^{0.5+x\log_x a}-a^{4.5}}$$

So make the thing under the square root non-negative.

$$a^x\sqrt{a}+a^4\sqrt{x}-a^x\sqrt{x}-a^4\sqrt{a}\ge0$$

Thus

$$(a^x-a^4)(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})\ge0$$

Note that this means $x=4$ is always a solution.

If $a\ge4$, then if $x\ge4$, $x\le a$. Therefore if $a\ge 5$ the function is undefined as $x=5$ is a solution. If $x<4$ then the first bracket is negative, the second is positive so we die immediately.

If $a\le4$, then if $x\le4$, $x\ge a$. Therefore if $a\le3$ the function is undefined as $x=3$ is a solution. If $x>4$ then the first term is positive whilst the second is negative so we die immediately.

Therefore the only solution is $a\in(3,5)$, the open interval from $3$ to $5$.

**Note:** negative $a,x$ die even faster because the term under the sqrt becomes imaginary, which is just bad.

As for where you can find more fun questions like this, basically I got good at maths by solving ISL problems, from here. These questions are designed to require ingenuity and creativity to solve, rather than formula memorisation and the like. Give them a shot! https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3223_imo_shortlist

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. Notice that I am asking for some other things in the question. Maybe you could give it a look and edit your answer?